# Can't Verify Hash Password in C#

Tags: c#, security, hash, passwords, salt

In C# language, my purpose is to hash password with hash_password(), then verify it with verify() methods. I hash and salt for password 's3cr3t', then check for two examples and return true if password is 's3cr3t' and return false for password 's3cr4t'.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Pbkdf2_test4
{
    public const int salt_size = 24;
    public const int hash_size = 24;
    public const int iteration = 100000;
    static byte[] salt1 = new byte[salt_size];

    private static Rfc2898DeriveBytes hash_password(string password)
    {
        RandomNumberGenerator generator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        byte[] salt = new byte[salt_size];
        generator.GetBytes(salt);

        salt1 = salt;

        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt1, iteration);
        return pbkdf2;
    }
    
    private static bool verify(Rfc2898DeriveBytes pw_hash, string password)
    {
        //data1 can be a string or contents of a file.
        string data1 = "Some test data";

        try
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes k1 = pw_hash;
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes k2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt1, iteration);

            // Encrypt the data.
            Aes encAlg = Aes.Create();
            encAlg.Key = k1.GetBytes(16);
            MemoryStream encryptionStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream encrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptionStream, encAlg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            byte[] utfD1 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(data1);

            encrypt.Write(utfD1, 0, utfD1.Length);
            encrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            encrypt.Close();
            byte[] edata1 = encryptionStream.ToArray();
            k1.Reset();

            // Try to decrypt, thus showing it can be round-tripped.
            Aes decAlg = Aes.Create();
            decAlg.Key = k2.GetBytes(16);
            decAlg.IV = encAlg.IV;
            MemoryStream decryptionStreamBacking = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream decrypt = new CryptoStream(decryptionStreamBacking, decAlg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            decrypt.Write(edata1, 0, edata1.Length);
            decrypt.Flush();
            decrypt.Close();
            k2.Reset();
            string data2 = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(decryptionStreamBacking.ToArray());

            if (!data1.Equals(data2))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void Run()
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pw_hash = hash_password("s3cr3t");
        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pw_hash.GetBytes(hash_size)));

        var result1 = verify(pw_hash, "s3cr3t");
        Console.WriteLine(result1);

        var result2 = verify(pw_hash, "s3cr4t");
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
}
```

My question, somehow there is a problem that for verify(pw_hash, "s3cr3t") that returns false however it should return true. In verify(), there is a problem but still could not understand because I give keys k1 and k2 true, but still does not receive hash/salt same, how can I fix this problem?

Apart from this, shuld I add anything to make password storage safest?

Comment: You need to save the salt1 for each user and use the same user salt each time to verify his/her password, your current method generate salt1 every time its called, therefore it can not verify even if you try till judgment day.

Comment: Catching all Exceptions without printing and just returning false is bad code style. Because of this you can not know why `false` is returned as there are two code paths that return false. Debug you code step-by-step or add log output to understand which code path is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is program to encrypt and decrypt pass

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Pbkdf2_test4 test4 = new Pbkdf2_test4();
            test4.Run();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Pbkdf2_test4
    {
        static string key = string.Empty;
        static string iv = string.Empty;

        public Pbkdf2_test4()
        {
            Aes encAlg = Aes.Create();
            encAlg.GenerateKey();
            key = Convert.ToBase64String(encAlg.Key);
            encAlg.GenerateIV();
            iv = Convert.ToBase64String(encAlg.IV);
        }

        public string Encrypt(string plainText, string Key, string IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(plainText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainText));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Key))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Key));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IV))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(IV));
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
                aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(IV);

                // Create an encrypt-or to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }                
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

        }

        public string Decrypt(string cipherText, string Key, string IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cipherText))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipherText));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Key))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Key));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IV))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(IV));

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = string.Empty;

            // Create an AesCryptoServiceProvider object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
                aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(IV);

                // Create a decrypt-or to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.

                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key is : " + key);
            Console.WriteLine("IV is : " + iv);

            string passord = "s3cr3t";
            string encryptedPassowrd = Encrypt(passord, key, iv);
            string decryptedPassowrd = Decrypt(encryptedPassowrd, key, iv);

            Console.WriteLine($"Password = {passord} and Encrypted password = {encryptedPassowrd}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Password = {passord} and Decrypted password = {decryptedPassowrd}");


            string passord1 = "s3cr4t";
            string encryptedPassowrd1 = Encrypt(passord1, key, iv);
            string decryptedPassowrd1 = Decrypt(encryptedPassowrd1, key, iv);

            Console.WriteLine($"Password = {passord1} and Encrypted password = {encryptedPassowrd1}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Password = {passord1} and Decrypted password = {decryptedPassowrd1}");

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is no good advise, whenever the password is just used to authenticate the user, it should be hashed and not encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the example in the documentation of [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-6.0). This function can be used for password hashing (PBKDF2), but then you don't need the encryption parts. The original use case of a key derivation function like PBKDF2 was to take a (weak) user password and turn it into a (strong) key which can then be used to encrypt data (thus the name key-derivation). Later one saw that the same functions are suitable to generate password hashes.

In your case I would recommend to use an appropriate library for password hashing, like [BCrypt.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BCrypt.Net-Next/). The usage would look like:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
string hashToStoreInDb = BCrypt.HashPassword(password);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from existingHashFromDb.
bool isPasswordCorrect = BCrypt.Verify(password, existingHashFromDb);
```